# How do you get bash to cd to your previous session directory on login?

Tags: bash, bashrc, cd

I would like to on ssh login, change directory to my previous one. (I'm the only user on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did.

```
# in .bash_logout
pwd > ~/.last_dir

# in .bashrc
cd "$(cat ~/.last_dir)"
```

Comment: In Bash you can do this without `cat`: `cd "$(< ~/.last_dir)"`